# Java Image array display

Tags: java, arrays, image, swing

I have created an array for Java with what I believe is the correct method, however, when I attempt to display the image in a button, nothing happens and I am unable to find what the reason behind it is (code updated thanks to Frakcool

```
private void showOnesSecsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    ImageIcon[] secs;
    secs = new ImageIcon[10]; Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        String location = "images\\" + i + ".png";
        secs[i] = new ImageIcon(location);
        oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(secs[i]);
    }

}
```

In the above snippet, the image is called from the secs[i] variable and then set as oneSecsDisplay new image.

**oneSecsDisplay** is a button that will show the image once another button called **showOneSecs** is pressed

I have 10 images from 0 to 9 that need to be displayed as a button is pressed; I was given the code:

```
int ones = Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText());
if (ones == 0) oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(filelocation);
if (ones == 0) oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(filelocation);
```

I don't think that this is good practice at it will be too repetitive and rather messy.

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong. Are they PNG pics, instead of JPG? Try changing `String location = "\\images\\" + i + ".png";` for `String location = "/images/" + i + ".png";` or for this one: `String location = "images/" + i + ".png";`. And if you have 10 images your for loop will only bring from 0-8 (i.e. only 9), change it to `for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)` or `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` so it brings 10 images instead of 9. Hope it helps. Good Luck

Comment: I checked to make sure, and you were right about the path being wrong, I forgot to move the folder from the src folder into the root, thank you for that! :) However the only image that shows is the image for number 9, from 0 to 8 all numbers show as 9

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Please or at least a bit more code? I guess your image 9 is shown because of another for loop somewhere else. And I also checked this line: `secs = new ImageIcon[9];` that will overflow as you have 10 images and it will store only 9.

Comment: added more code to the original post :)

Comment: Where in your code do you add the image to the button? Please again, I suggest you to read the link I provided about [How to make a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Help us to help you :) Btw what does `oneSecsDisplay` is?

Comment: The statement Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText()); in your code does nothing. It returns an integer, but it is not stored anywhere

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out for me, how would I reconcile this? I could separate and store the value outside of the for statement I believe?

Comment: What are you trying to achive by parseing oneSecs? What is oneSecs anyway?

Comment: oneSecs is a textfield that i grab the value of 0 to 9 and then I match it against the array to pick the image 'x.png' x being the value of i to choose the image

Comment: Im confused. How many images are you trying to display? Just the one or multiple?

Comment: One at a time, once the value is checked against i, it should display the corresponding number. For example if the number is entered as 7, the image for 7 will show up on the oneSecsDisplay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to set just the correct image, there is no need for arrays or for loops. Try this instead:

```
private void showOnesSecsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int index = Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText());
    String location = "images\\" + index + ".png";
    oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new ImageIcon(location));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this code is perfect! Was wracking my brain on how to make this easier haha!